# ffmpeg shows "get_buffer() failed". Is this a bug?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, video-encoding, hardware-acceleration

ffmpeg version 2023-06-19-git-1617d1a752-full_build-www.gyan.dev

i7-1255U, Windows 11

The command line is

```
"ffmpeg.exe"  -y  -hwaccel qsv  -ss 00:00:03.461  -to 00:00:12.009  -i "input.mov"   -c:v h264_qsv -global_quality 25 -look_ahead 1 -preset veryslow -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ac 2 -ab 128k output.mp4
```

The "input.mov" is mjpeg.

The result is:

```
[mjpeg_qsv @ 0000019930260080] get_buffer() failed
[vist#0:0/mjpeg @ 000001993025ff00] Error submitting packet to decoder: Cannot allocate memory
[mjpeg_qsv @ 0000019930260080] get_buffer() failed
[vist#0:0/mjpeg @ 000001993025ff00] Error submitting packet to decoder: Cannot allocate memory
[mjpeg_qsv @ 0000019930260080] get_buffer() failed
[vist#0:0/mjpeg @ 000001993025ff00] Error submitting packet to decoder: Cannot allocate memory
[mjpeg_qsv @ 0000019930260080] get_buffer() failed
[vist#0:0/mjpeg @ 000001993025ff00] Error submitting packet to decoder: Cannot allocate memory
[mjpeg_qsv @ 0000019930260080] get_buffer() failed
[vist#0:0/mjpeg @ 000001993025ff00] Error submitting packet to decoder: Cannot allocate memory
```

The messages above repeats many many many times. Finally, it shows:

```
[vist#0:0/mjpeg @ 000001993025ff00] Error submitting EOF to decoder: Cannot allocate memory
```

I tried the same command line on a very old version, and it works fine. Is this a bug or there is something new that comes with the new version?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org.  Looks to be a regression with hwaccel qsv since 2022-08-03

Comment: Try adding `-max_muxing_queue_size` to the command to increase the queue size.

Comment: Thank you. Tried it. didn't work. @harrymc

Answer (score 0):

Open a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org. This looks to be a regression with hwaccel qsv since 2022-08-03.

In the meanwhile, you can directly specify a decoder if you know the input video codec and it is supported by QSV. In your case, it would be `-c:v mjpeg_qsv -ss 00:00:03.461  -to 00:00:12.009 -i "input.mov"`

Comment: Thank you. I just switched to the old version.